# Bootstrap Images on top of another

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using bootstrap and I have two images on top of another using positions like so:

```
<img src="/images/coverphoto.jpg" alt="First slide" width="100%" height="300" style="position: relative;padding: 0;">
<img src="/images/logo.png" style="position: absolute;">
```

I am trying to get the logo to display over the banner; However, this is what is displayed:
http://gyazo.com/018a5818f48d3310047fdad5ebd10fc7

I am not really sure why as the code for that navbar is underneath both of the image tags.  How do I fix this/what am I doing wrong.

Thanks in advance

Comment: do you have css for this?  looking at your html there seems to be no reason to expect the png photo to appear above the jpg because you don't have top/bottom attributes.

Comment: also from your screenshot it looks like the png is below the jpg.  z-index that up.

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by do you have css for this, I am using the twitter-bootstrap-3 library and the inline styles you see above, I am not using more than that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set a `position:relative` the next `position: absolute` will have its reference point the end of the relative element. if you want one on top of the other try:

```
<img src="/images/coverphoto.jpg" alt="First slide" width="100%" height="300" style="position: absolute;padding: 0;">
<img src="/images/logo.png" style="position: absolute;">
```

Comment: Well I guess we are getting somewhere, but now that navbar has jumped up http://gyazo.com/151bcc5550fe18ea0c4ac6e505cef62f

Comment: That is because when an element is absolute positioned it looses its height and width for the elements beneath it. What you can do it reposition your elements. Try playing with their properties. I guess that's the best way to properly understand how positioning works. Cheers!

Comment: I put a margin-top on the navbar beneath it, seems to work, thanks